# Version 1.7.6 Import Error in line 890 of sanbox.py when running dev_appserver

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm having some dificulty gettung 1.7.6 running. Getting the following error:

```
INFO     2013-03-20 08:39:10,233 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8086
ERROR    2013-03-20 08:39:13,768 wsgi.py:219] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 353, in __getattr__
    self._update_configs()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 289, in _update_configs
    self._registry.initialize()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 164, in initialize
    import_func(self._modname)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 890, in load_module
    raise ImportError
ImportError
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. I raised an issue in the appengine issue tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9008&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

The problem appear to be old pyc files in the project directory. I removed them with:

find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -rf {} \;

After restarting the server the issue was fixed for me.

If that does not help, you can use the old development server: run "old_dev_appserver.py ." + any arguments you require for now.

Answer (score 0):

Here I decided some startup problems, deleting the project and adding an existing project. I did it and my app started again normally.

Comment: This did not fix the problem for me.